# Dúvida sobre compilar e linkar bibliotecas (C++)

Tags: c++, compilação, biblioteca, linkagem

Estou usando a IDE CodeBlocks e gostaria de usar as funções de uma biblioteca externa chamada Chilkat no meu código.
Eu consigo fazer a IDE ler o header, mas quando eu tento usar alguma função ou objeto da biblioteca, o código não compila.

O código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CkSpider.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    CkSpider miranha;
    miranha.Initialize("www.chilkatsoft.com");
    cout<<"Funciona"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Os erros são todos do tipo:

```
..\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ChilkatSocket.o):ChilkatSocket.cpp|| undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'|
..\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ChilkatSocket.o):ChilkatSocket.cpp|| undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'|
..\libchilkat-9.5.0.a(ChilkatSocket.o):ChilkatSocket.cpp|| undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'|
```

Além disso, na página da biblioteca (https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_mingw.asp#getStarted) existe algumas instruções de como linkar e compilar a biblioteca, mas eu não sei onde ou como usar esses parâmetros:

> The -Wl,--enable-auto-import options may be required when linking. Also, link with libcrypt32.a, libws2_32.a, and libdnsapi.a as shown below:

```
g++ -Wl,--enable-auto-import linkSample.cpp -o"linkSample.exe" -L. -lchilkat-9.5.0
    -L/MinGW/lib -lcrypt32 -lws2_32 -ldnsapi
```

Como faço para linkar e compilar essa biblioteca no CodeBlocks?
Agradeço resposta em texto ou até algum vídeo que me dê um norte.